# Fastest way to find and replace multiple items in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I have two arrays with about 1000 prices and sizes in order from smallest to largest called `tempArrayBuy` and `tempArraySell`.

```
let tempArrayBuy = [Orders]()
let tempArraySell = [Orders]()

struct Orders:Codable {
    let price : Double
    let size : Double

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        price = Double(try container.decode(String.self)) ?? 0.0
        size = Double(try container.decode(String.self)) ?? 0.0
    }

    init(_ orderEntryChange: OrderChangesFeed) {
        price = orderEntryChange.price ?? 0.0
        size = orderEntryChange.size ?? 0.0
    }

}
```

I am getting changes that need to be made to the two arrays above through a websocket feed. I need to find the correct price in the `tempArrayBuy` and the replace that quantity with the quantity in the `OrderBookChangesFeed` item.

Here is the format of the data from the websocket. I have an array of changes.

```
let changesNeeded = [OrderChangesFeed]()
```

This is the structure of the data.

```
struct OrderChangesFeed : Codable {
    let side:String        
    let price : Double
    let size : Double

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        side = try container.decode(String.self)
        price = Double(try container.decode(String.self)) ?? 0.0
        size = Double(try container.decode(String.self)) ?? 0.0
    }
}
```

If the side is `buy` then it needs to update the `buyTempArray` and if it is `sell` it needs to update the `sellTempArray`. If the price from the change websocket (`OrderBookChangesFeed`) does not exist in the array, it needs to be added with the quantity/size given and if the quantity/size associated to a specific price in the changes websocket is 0 then it needs to be removed from the tempArray.

Here is what I am doing now. But I feel like there is a faster way to do this. I am getting about 10-20+ changes in a second so speed is the most important thing here.

```
for item in changesNeeded {
    if item.side == "buy"{
        if let tempInex = self.tempArrayBuy.index(where: {$0.price==item.price}) {
            if item.size == 0 {
                self.tempArrayBuy.remove(at: tempInex)
            }else {
                self.tempArrayBuy[tempInex] = Orders(item)
            }             
        }else {
            //Insert at the right spot in array. The array is sorted numerically by price. I am not sure what a fast way to do this would be.
        }
    }else {
        //Do the same thing for sell side
    }
}
```

I also am not sure how to insert it in the right spot numerically. Any help on this would be amazing!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162068/discussion-on-question-by-nevin-jethmalani-fastest-way-to-find-and-replace-multi).

Answer (score 0):

Your two Orders arrays should not be arrays, they should be dictionaries with price as the key and size as the value.

```
var tempBuy: [Double: Double] = [:]
var tempSell: [Double: Double] = [:]
```

To initially fill out the dictionaries above with your orders arrays, you can:

```
tempBuy = Dictionary<Double, Double>(uniqueKeysWithValues: buyOrders.map { ($0.price, $0.size) }) // the same for the sell orders.
```

Then you can simply:

```
for item in changesNeeded {
    switch item.side {
    case "buy":
        tempBuy[item.price] = item.size
    case "sell":
        tempSell[item.price] = item.size
    default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

QED.

If you really need arrays of these things, then:

```
var tempArrayBuy: [Orders] {
    return tempBuy
        .map { Orders(price: $0.0, size: $0.1) }
        .sorted(by: { $0.price < $1.price })
}
```

-- EDIT --

If you *really* want to keep them as a sorted array, the wrap the whole thing up in a function.

```
func updateArrays(changesNeeded: [OrderChangesFeed], buy: inout [Orders], sell: inout [Orders]) {
    var tempBuy = [Double: Double](uniqueKeysWithValues: buy.map { ($0.price, $0.size) })
    var tempSell = [Double: Double](uniqueKeysWithValues: sell.map { ($0.price, $0.size) })
    for item in changesNeeded {
        switch item.side {
        case "buy":
            tempBuy[item.price] = item.size
        case "sell":
            tempSell[item.price] = item.size
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
    buy = tempBuy
        .map { Orders(price: $0.0, size: $0.1) }
        .sorted(by: { $0.price < $1.price })
    sell = tempSell
        .map { Orders(price: $0.0, size: $0.1) }
        .sorted(by: { $0.price < $1.price })
}
```

Comment: if I want to very frequently get the 10 lowest key values for example, it makes more sense to turn them into an array that is sorted right?

Comment: I am parsing the JSON using codable so how would I change the dictionary passed to me as a JSOn array into a dictionary of prices and sizes? I know how to do it but I want to know what the best way to do it would be.

Comment: If you just want the 10 lowest prices for example, do a partial sort on the keys and map them to an array of Orders. But chances are, a quick sort just before getting the first 10 would be cheeper than constantly doing a linear search for each change order.

Comment: If you have price as the key and size as the value you lose the link to the Orders struct itself.  It would be better to have the price as the key and the Orders struct as the value like this `var tempBuy: [Double: Orders] = [:]`.  I might go further and change the Orders struct to a class so that it can be implicitly shared and then you could have a dictionary and a sorted array but both pointing to the same Orders.  You could then update the dictionary when something changes and regenerate the sorted array.

Comment: Representing price as a double and using it as a dictionary key is rather dangerous.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth The dictionary can easily be mapped back into Orders as I show. They are value types so there is no sense of "loosing the struct" as long as you have all the information.

Comment: @Sulthan Agreed, I just did it because the OP represented price this way. It's a bad idea though.

Comment: @Sulthan why is that? What is a better way to do it?

Comment: how do I change the `Orders` struct to a dictionary?

Comment: @DanielT. I agree it doesn't really matter in this case but I like to think of the future.  Today it's just a price and size but tomorrow they decide to send a description as well and perhaps an ID and maybe a colour, etc.  So now you need to refactor everything where as it you start with the Orders struct in the dictionary it all still works.  (plus as I said I might decide to use a class instead of a struct)

Comment: @Sulthan You shouldn't really use a Double to represent any kind of currency value.  Use a `Decimal` instead.